# What's the shortest or clearest way to turn a function call into a no-argument function object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

The contenders that I'm aware of:

```
function() { the.call.I(want).to(make); }

the.call.I(want).to.bind(null, make);

()=>{ the.call.I(want).to(make); }
```

None of which are all the way awesome. Are there any others? Libraries and Node packages welcome.

Comment: This is one of the things. `bind()` is made for.  Why would it not work just fine?  When you have several solutions already, it's not clear what else you're looking for?

Comment: Otherwise known as [currying](https://www.google.com/search?q=currying+javascript)

Comment: I reckon this is going to get opinionated...

Comment: @spender - especially when there's no definition of "clearest" and the OP already knows about `.bind()` which is made for this.  Seems like a poor question as written.

Comment: Yeah, I guess now that there's an answer, I realize I don't really know what would constitute an answer that I'd give the green check to...

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think bind is the best way to go. Another option is to use something like underscore or lodash. From the lo-dash documentation site:

```
var curried = _.curry(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a + b + c);
});

curried(1)(2)(3);
// → 6

curried(1, 2)(3);
// → 6

curried(1, 2, 3);
// → 6
```